# How to parse JSON tidal information from worldtides.info?

Tags: json, bash, jq

My goal is to parse the result of [www.worldtides.info](http://www.worldtides.info).  I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm scripting with Linux.

I have an API key and the curl request is something like:

```
curl -s "http://www.worldtides.info/api?extremes&lat=my_latitude&lon=my_longitude&key=my_api_key"
```

Which gets a result like this:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "requestLat": "my_latitude",
  "requestLon": "my_longitude",
  "extremes": [
    {
      "dt": 1459680132,
      "date": "2016-04-03T10:42+0000",
      "height": 0.7343567325036922,
      "type": "High"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1459702028,
      "date": "2016-04-03T16:47+0000",
      "height": -0.8438121322770741,
      "type": "Low"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1459724478,
      "date": "2016-04-03T23:01+0000",
      "height": 1.0419712550773803,
      "type": "High"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1459747135,
      "date": "2016-04-04T05:18+0000",
      "height": -1.1049607153344834,
      "type": "Low"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1459769354,
      "date": "2016-04-04T11:29+0000",
      "height": 1.1012796430343657,
      "type": "High"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1459791366,
      "date": "2016-04-04T17:36+0000",
      "height": -1.204313872235808,
      "type": "Low"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1459813613,
      "date": "2016-04-04T23:46+0000",
      "height": 1.3452661348073778,
      "type": "High"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1459835931,
      "date": "2016-04-05T05:58+0000",
      "height": -1.4062688322894952,
      "type": "Low"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using jq, I want to get the times of high and low tides for the current day and tomorrow, but when I try this:

```
.result[].type
```

But it gives me an error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)`
```

---

I know I can get the type of tide it is using this:

```
.extremes[].type
```

the result is:

```
High
Low
etc...
```

and the time of the tide using this:

```
.extremes[].date
```

the result is:

```
2016-04-03T10:42+0000
2016-04-03T16:47+0000
etc...
```

So, how do I combine the results together to get an output like this?

```
2016-04-03T10:42+0000 High
2016-04-03T16:47+0000 Low
etc...
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: There is no `result` key, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please submit a separate question for the edited second half of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
curl -s "http://www.worldtides.info/api?extremes&lat=my_latitude&lon=my_longitude&key=my‌​_api_key"| jq -r ".extremes[] | .date + .type"
```

Should give you **both** the date/time and High/Low tide output for each entry.

---

**Basically**, you need to use `extremes` NOT `result`.  There is **no** `result` key, hence `jq` is giving you messages about `null`.